# UIActivityIndicatorView not animating

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios5

I keep getting the UIActivityIndicatorView into view but not animating.

I'm not doing extensive processing I just add my class as a subview to the view of an UITableViewController and do nothing else.

Here is the class I use to layout my UIActivityIndicatorView:

```
#import "UIXLoaderView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface UIXLoaderView () {
@private
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
}
@end

@implementation UIXLoaderView

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Measure Loading string
        NSString *loadingText = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"Loading...");
        CGSize textSize = [loadingText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] forWidth:280 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

        // Create activity gauge
        activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        // now set our frame
        if (activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width > textSize.width) {
            [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width + 20, activityIndicatorView.frame.size.height + textSize.height + 30)];
        } else {
            [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width + 20, activityIndicatorView.frame.size.height + textSize.height + 30)];
        }

        // Add the activity gauge into the view
        [activityIndicatorView setFrame:CGRectMake(((self.frame.size.width - activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width) / 2) , 10, activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width, activityIndicatorView.frame.size.width)];
        [self addSubview:activityIndicatorView];

        // Create and add the label
        UILabel *loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((self.frame.size.width - textSize.width) / 2), activityIndicatorView.frame.origin.y + activityIndicatorView.frame.size.height + 10, textSize.width, textSize.height)];
        [loadingLabel setText:loadingText];
        [loadingLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        [loadingLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
        [loadingLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [loadingLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self addSubview:loadingLabel];

        // rounded corners
        [[self layer] setCornerRadius:9.0];
        //[[self layer] setBorderWidth:1.0];
        //[[self layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

        // back color
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)removeFromSuperview {
    // Stop animating
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

    // Call super
    [super removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    // Move to center
    [self setCenter:[[self superview] center]]; 

    // Call super
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    // Animate
    [activityIndicatorView setHidden:NO];
    [activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}

@end
```

The header file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIXLoaderView : UIView

@end
```

Inside a UITableViewController I just call it in the following way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // If no data start loading animation
    if (!self->data) {
        // Show the loading view
        loaderView = [[UIXLoaderView alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:loaderView];
    }

}
```

The starngest thing here is the animation will start if I tap and move the tableView, but it won't animate once the control is loaded... and I can't fugure out what is happening here. Any clues?

Comment: the code seems correct; the only strange thing is that you're adding your custom view as a subview of the table view controller, and this view is a UITableView. Now a table view is quite a particular cell and so adding a custom view on it can have some strange side effect, like this; can you try to use a basic view controller with a simple UIView as superview and then add inside this view the two children: the table and your custom view? sorry I'm on my iPad and I cannot check, this is just an idea not an answer!

Comment: Well I did try out with a different approach; instead of adding the view as a subview of the UITableViewController I added it to aplication UIWindow and it worked. Not as I would like it to work, since I don't want to be calling the App delegate each time I just want to display the activity indicator, but fine for a test. I think the problem is related to view animations.

Answer (score 1):

Given your implementation, you don't need to start/stop animating in `didMoveToSuperview` and `removeFromSuperView`. Set the `activityIndictorView` to animate when you create it. It will only be visible when `UIXLoaderView` is added to it's superview and it will go away when you get rid of the `UIXLoaderView`.

Comment: I've tried starting it in several places. In the constructor, by creating the methods startAnimating and stopAnimating as in the UIActivityIndicatorView... but on the UITableViewController it will only animate after scrolling the tableView. Quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start the animation before to call super?

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't work. I've also tried calling it from the UITableViewController but got the same results. It appears and seems to start the animation as I can see the gauge but it seems stuck, as if the thread was stuck on a long process but this is not the case and it will spin on and on once I scroll the tableView. But before touching to scroll the tableView it just seems the application is not responding with a static gauge.